# How can I magnify an infinity corrected image onto a camera surface?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

I know that the typical setup with a camera will place the CMOS sensor at `I(3)` in the image below, and that this magnification is dictated by the tube lens focal length `f_tl` and the effective focal length of the Objective, `f_obj`. Namely, `M = f_tl / f_obj`. However, I want to put the CMOS camera behind another lens to get more magnification out of the system (e.g. where the eye is, it gets a magnified image from the eyepiece). Any references on how to do this/design it?

[image: inifinty objective]

Answer (score 0):

This would result in an aberrated image. To increase magnification of the objective simply use a longer EFL tube lens. Note that if your system is diffraction limited you would be sacrificing field of view without any improvement in resolution. Also, using a longer-than-designed-for tube lens you cannot benefit from the increased numerical aperture of a higher magnification objective.

See magnification & FOV in this link:
https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5834